# file_put_contents doesn't work when accessed in browser

Tags: php, apache

I use php5.6 and Apache2.4.6 in centOS7.5
I put a php file in `/var/www/html`

like this :

```
<?php    
echo (__DIR__ . "/test.text");    
file_put_contents(__DIR__ . "/test.text","test text");
```

when I access this file through web browser(google chrome), file_put_contents do not function. 
but,when I execute this file in console, file_put_contents do function. it make `test.text` file.

Is this problem due to server setting? or some php function doesn't work in access by a browser?

this is httpd/error_log

```
[Tue Oct 30 13:35:13.191011 2018] [:error] [pid 15037] [client XX.XXX.XX.XXX:29220] PHP Warning:  
file_put_contents(/var/www/html/test.text): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/fpc2.php on line 3
```

but, this file's permission is 777.

Comment: The console will execute as your console user, where the web browser will execute as your web server user.. Make sure the directory is writable for the web server user, normally `www-data` when using Apache with `mod_php` You can check it by using `echo (is_writable(__DIR__) ? 'writable' : 'not authorized');`

Comment: SELinux may be the problem. You can try https://blog.lysender.com/2015/07/centos-7-selinux-php-apache-cannot-writeaccess-file-no-matter-what/

Comment: What do you get with echo (__DIR__ . "/test.text");

Comment: @T.Murakami When I run your code, I get output in my browser `E:\Study\Mywork\xampp\htdocs\udhav/test.text` , And in this path I follow a path, it becomes a file and it has a **test text** output.

Comment: I get both echo messages : ```/var/www/html/testphp/test.text```

Comment: I added ```echo (is_writable(__DIR__) ? 'writable' : 'not authorized');``` in this script.   this messages is ```not authorized```　oh...

Comment: @blue qn  status of SELinux is disabled.

Comment: @fyrye oh...I realised this file's permission is not writable. this was a little problem. thanks!

Comment: File permissions, is my first thought.  Opps I see you figured that out already, all things being equal, code will run the same, if it doesn't it's almost always the environment.  In this case what user is PHP running under.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right.  So it is a permissions problem.  You need to make sure that the "user" that runs the php code has permission to write into the directory.  I don't know to which user to give the permission, but it may be "web".  Try:

sudo chgrp -R web /var/www/html

then

sudo chmod -R g+w *

Comment: This is better as a comment, not   an answer

Comment: I agree.  Stackoverflow wouldn't let me post a direct comment.  Too much a noob, I guess.

Comment: Oh ok, sorry about that